# Enabling power supply using microcontroller: schematic review

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, ldo, review

I am using two regulators in my design. They need to be enabled by a microcontroller.

The microcontroller is working at 5 V. The regualtor P/N is a [TPS62160QDSGRQ1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62160-q1.pdf) and the microcontroller is an [FS32K148UJT0VLQT_LQFP_144L](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K1xx.pdf).

My schematic is given below. May I know your comments about it?

[image]

Comment: The EN pin has a pull-up and so the MCU can only _disable_ the regulator, never enable it because that's the default state. Or maybe the IC symbol was incorrectly drawn: active low signals are drawn with a line above the signal name or alternatively `/EN`.

Comment: There is voltage divider created by 100K and 33R so when the signal from microcontroller is low the voltage at EN pin is 1.65mV and when signal from microcontroller is high the voltage at EN pin is nearly equal to 5V

Comment: Yes but you wrote that it needs to be enabled by a microcontroller, which isn't true. If the microcontroller explodes in a puff of smoke or if it is merely booting, as MCUs tend to do before going active, then the voltage regulator is _enabled_.

Comment: In plain English: active high signals, as this turned out to be (I now checked the datasheet), need to have a pull-down, not a pull-up.

Comment: Lundin has it in a nutshell. If you need the MCU to enable the regulator, your design is incorrect. The MCU must be active and able to pull that GPIO line low to disable the regulator. This means there will be finnicky situations where you *will* find the regulator unexpectedly enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF uC operates on 5V then use a pulldown on EN and drive EN from the uC pin.

If Vhi_uC is say 3V3:
Use an NPN transistor.

- Connect collector to EN.
- Connect pullup to EN to Vdd_MCU5V as you have done now.
- Connect base to 3V3 via say 10k.
- Drive emitter from uC pin.

This gives you a voltage upconverter with same polarity in and out.